React-instagram reels clone: problem with scrollIntoView() method and proper index of current video handling
Hi everyone I am struggling to develop an instagram reels clone.
You can see the design in the image.
So, the idea is I fetch 1 video by param in the link and 4 random, then when the second or previous reel appears on-screen program changes the index of the current video, changes the URL, and when the end of the array is reached new videos are fetched(it is not implemented yet, I face problems even with static Array of 5 videos).
So I face two problems, when scrolling down from 0-video to 1-video back and forth everything is okay, however when the user scrolls to 2-video or 3-video and then scrolls up to the previous, the event "scroll down" and "scroll up" reacts at the same time on div that is upper from current. (use effects with isNextIntersecting and isPrevIntersecting). This at the same time increases and decreases the value of currentShotIndex, sometimes it works like 2->3 and 2->1 at the same time, and the index becomes incorrect after some time.)
The second problem is I want the program to automatically scroll to the next/previous video until the video is in the middle of the component (just like in reels, TikTok, and shorts) so the user scrolls until 50 percent of the lower/upper video and the program than auto scrolls. Currently, the program does it only for the first load of the page and when the user scrolls from 0-video to 1-video, then it doesn't work.
user interface
case when scrolling up, but programm goes in "scroll down case"
I would appreciate any help or advice.
Component
function ViewShot(props) {
    const params = useParams();
    const history = useHistory();
    const [refNext, isNextIntersecting] = useOnScreen({ threshold: 0.5 })
    const [prevRef, isPrevIntersecting] = useOnScreen({ threshold: 0.5 })
    const [shots, setShots] = React.useState([]);
    const containerRef = React.useRef(null)
    const [wasLowerScroll, setWasLowerScroll] = React.useState(false)
    const [wasUpperScroll, setWasUpperScroll] = React.useState(false)
    const [firstLoad, setFirstLoad] = React.useState(true)
    const [currentShotIndex, setCurrentShotIndex] = React.useState(0);
    const [copySuccess, setCopySuccess] = React.useState(false);
    const querybyid = useGetShotByIdQuery(params.id);
    const queryrandom = useGetRandomShotsQuery(4);
    const { refetch: refetchShotByParams, data: shotbyid, error, isLoading } = querybyid
    const { refetch: refetchrandom, data: randomshots, error: randomerror, isLoading: randomLoad } = queryrandom
    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (querybyid.status == 'fulfilled' && queryrandom.status == 'fulfilled') {
            console.log('first useeffect')
            setShots([shotbyid, ...randomshots]);
        }
    }, [querybyid, queryrandom]);
    React.useEffect(() => {
        const fetchshot = async () => {
            if (isNextIntersecting && refNext.current) {
                const nextShotIndex = currentShotIndex + 1;
                console.log("scroll down - ", nextShotIndex)
                if (nextShotIndex < shots.length) {
                    setCurrentShotIndex(nextShotIndex);
                    //console.log("url update, set next shot");
                    if (shots) {
                        //   console.log("index after down - ", nextShotIndex)
                        history.push(`/shots/${shots[nextShotIndex]?._id}`);
                    }
                } else {
                    await refetchrandom();
                    setCurrentShotIndex(nextShotIndex);
                    console.log("fetching new random shots");
                    if (shots)
                        history.push(`/shots/${shots[nextShotIndex]?._id}`);
                }
                scrollToDiv(refNext)
            }
        }
        fetchshot();
    }, [isNextIntersecting, refNext]);
    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (isPrevIntersecting && !firstLoad && prevRef.current) {
            const prevShotIndex = currentShotIndex - 1;
            if (prevShotIndex >= 0) {
                console.log("scroll up - ", prevShotIndex)
                setCurrentShotIndex(prevShotIndex);
                history.push(`/shots/${shots[prevShotIndex]?._id}`);
                scrollToDiv(prevRef)
            }
        }
        setFirstLoad(false)
        //console.log(isPrevIntersecting)
    }, [isPrevIntersecting, prevRef]);
    const scrollToDiv = (element) => {
        if (element){
            console.log(element.current)
            element.current.scrollIntoView()
        }
 return (
        <div style={{ ...container, ...custom }} className={`bg-light-color my-[100px]`}>
            <div className="p-[15px] h-[100%] flex">
                <Menuleft />
                <div style={{ flex: '1 85%', ...sliderContainer }} className="h-[100%] px-4" ref={containerRef}>
                    {shots.length > 0 ? (
                        <>
                            {shots.map((shot, index) => {
                                return (
                                    <div copyref={index === currentShotIndex + 1 ? "next"
                                        : (index === currentShotIndex - 1) ? "prevRef" : null} key={index} style={shotdiv}
                                        ref={index === currentShotIndex + 1 ? refNext
                                            : (index === currentShotIndex - 1) ? prevRef : null}>
                                        {shot && (
                                            <div className="h-[100%]">
                                                <ShotPlayer style={player} videoId={shot.video} />
                                            </div>
                                        )}
                                        <div style={iconContainerStyle}>
                                            <div className="shadow-lg cursor-pointer" style={iconStyle}>
                                                <img className='h-[100%] p-1' src={like} alt="Like" />
                                                <div style={text}>{formatViews(shot?.likes)}</div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="shadow-lg cursor-pointer" style={iconStyle}>
                                                <img className='h-[100%] p-1' src={dislike} alt="Dislike" />
                                                <span style={text}>{formatViews(shot?.dislikes)}</span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="shadow-lg cursor-pointer" style={iconStyle}>
                                                <img className='h-[100%] p-2' src={comment} alt="Comment" />
                                                <span style={text}>{formatViews(shot?.comments?.length)}</span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="shadow-lg cursor-pointer" style={iconStyle}
                                                onClick={handleCopy}
                                            >
                                                <img className='h-[100%] p-2' src={share} alt="Share" />
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="shadow-lg cursor-pointer" style={iconStyle} onClick={() => history.push('/film?q=' + shot?.linksToOriginal[0])}>
                                                <div className='h-[100%] p-1 font-serif font-bold  flex items-center justify-center'>
                                                    Full
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                )
                            })}
                        </>
                    ) : (
                        <>
                            <h1>Nothing to show here</h1>
                        </>
                    )}
                    {copySuccess && <span className="flex justify-center align-middle">URL copied to clipboard!</span>}
                </div>
            </div>

Custom hook isonscreen
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

const useOnScreen = (options) => {
    const ref = useRef();
    const [isIntersecting, setIntersecting] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
            ([entry]) => setIntersecting(entry.isIntersecting),
            options
        );

        if (ref.current) {
            observer.observe(ref.current);
        }

        return () => {
            if (ref.current) {
                observer.unobserve(ref.current);
            }
        };
    }, [ref, options]);

    return [ref, isIntersecting];
};

export default useOnScreen;

Scrolling divs, change url based on id of entry associated to div. Acctually resulted - wrong indexes, program doesnt scroll by itself

Try this:
Add State for Scroll Handling:
const [isScrolling, setIsScrolling] = useState(false);

Updated the useEffect to include a check for the isScrolling flag, ensuring only one scroll event updates the state at a time.
useEffect(() => {
    const handleScroll = async () => {
        if (isScrolling) return;
        setIsScrolling(true);

        if (isNextIntersecting && refNext.current) {
            const nextShotIndex = currentShotIndex + 1;
            if (nextShotIndex < shots.length) {
                setCurrentShotIndex(nextShotIndex);
                history.push(`/shots/${shots[nextShotIndex].id}`);
            } else {
                await fetchData();
                setCurrentShotIndex(nextShotIndex);
                history.push(`/shots/${shots[nextShotIndex].id}`);
            }
            scrollToDiv(refNext);
        } else if (isPrevIntersecting && prevRef.current) {
            const prevShotIndex = currentShotIndex - 1;
            if (prevShotIndex >= 0) {
                setCurrentShotIndex(prevShotIndex);
                history.push(`/shots/${shots[prevShotIndex].id}`);
                scrollToDiv(prevRef);
            }
        }

        setTimeout(() => setIsScrolling(false), 1000);
    };
    handleScroll();
}, [isNextIntersecting, isPrevIntersecting]);

Modify the scrollToDiv function to ensure smooth scrolling and align the video in the middle of the component:
const scrollToDiv = (element) => {
    if (element && element.current) {
        element.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'center' });
    }
};

Let me know!

Hi thank you for fast answer, but problems keep, I have attached one more photo after first one, maybe that could help
